# Not sure where to put my Java library needed for my class assignments

Tags: java, vim, import, shared-libraries

I'm starting a Java programming class at UCSD next week and I'm trying to prepare over the weekend. There is a library called objectdraw.jar which comes with the book we will be using for our class projects. I am currently using Vim for my Java projects because most assignments will be simple and I am still trying to learn and master Vim.

Now to the question:

In C++ I am able to use #include with angled brackets <> to include headers in a default folder and #include with quotes "" to include local header files. It seems from what I've found with some Internet searches that you can't do that with Java.

I tried putting the objectdraw.jar file in the same folder as my .java file for the first assignment, but it doesn't find the library using the following code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import objectdraw.*;
```

When I searched online, the Gentoo HOWTO mentioned setting a CLASSPATH but then mentions that those instructions should be considered deprecated, but doesn't provide further instructions.

The website where I downloaded the library http://eventfuljava.cs.williams.edu/library.html does not provide instructions for Vim, but does for other IDEs like Eclipse and Netbeans.

Can anyone tell me where I would place the .jar file to ALL my projects can find it, or can anyone point me to a resource where I might find an answer. I seem to be asking the wrong questions when searching online.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html) for how to set classpath using command line options to any of the java sdk tools - java, javac. The page shows how to set the environment variable CLASSPATH as well as how to use the switch -classpath.

In your case if you have the objectdraw.jar in the same directory as your source files, then you will need a command like this to compile -

```
javac -classpath . MyClass.java
```

and this to run

```
java -classpath . MyClass
```

You can also provide the full path to a jar file in the classpath and add multiple directories and jars. Such as `-classpath .:/path/to/my.jar:/some/other/directory` note paths and separators for *nix environment. on Windows it would be ; and \

Edit: Note comment below for quoting paths with spaces in them.

Comment: If your paths contain spaces, you must surround the the entire parameter with double quotes.  So if your class path needs to contain multiple jars:  -classpath ".;c:\some other path\to a.jar;c:\some big\path to\a.jar" MyClass.java

Comment: One additional question now. The program compiled without error, but when I try to run it using "java -cp ../java_libraries/objectdraw.jar TouchyWindow", I'm getting an error message: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TouchyWidndow/class". I'm running that command from within the folder where I have the compiled TouchyWindow.class file. Any ideas?

Comment: You must add the current directory to the classpath. So add `-cp .:../javalibs/objectdraw.jar ...` like that. It doesn't know to look for the class TouchyWindow in your current directory where you are running the command from.

Comment: OK, that changed the error message to 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main' ... Sorry to bother you with tedious questions like this. The book doesn't spend any time covering how to set up your Java environment.

Comment: Does your class define a method with this signature - `public static void main(String args[])` ?

Comment: It does not, but from the reading, that method should not be required because the objectdraw.jar library contains it. Am I possibly misunderstanding that part?

Comment: Whatever class you are running must define that method. Even if a jar file has some classes that define `main`, your main class in this case `TouchyWindow` must define it. That is the program entry point. Akin to the `int main(...)` of C.